# How to hide options of a form with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

i have a special problem. I am using a theme which uses taxonomies to assign users posts to a board of the user. So every user can create their own board and assign his post to one board. I am using wordpress frontent uploader and can add the taxonomy board with a dropdown to the form. That works fine.

I just have one problem. The user can select everyones board in the dropdown.

Taxonomy structure looks like this:

```
Parent: User ID 
Child: boardname
```

So my output looks like this:

```
<div class="wpuf-fields wpuf_board_select_123_321">

<select data-required="yes" data-type="select" name='board[]' id='board[]' class='board wpuf_board_123' >
    <option value='-1'>&#8212; Select &#8212;</option>
    <option class="level-0" value="3">1</option>            // value is term ID // Content is User ID // parent
    <option class="level-1" value="17">User Board </option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="26">User Board</option>  // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="106">User Board</option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="62">User Board</option>  // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="148">User Board</option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-0" value="191">10</option>         // value is term ID // Content is User ID // User has no boards
    <option class="level-0" value="193">11</option>         // value is term ID // Content is User ID // User has no boards
    <option class="level-0" value="10">2</option>           // value is term ID // Content is User ID // parent
    <option class="level-1" value="123">User Board</option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="124">User Board</option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="192">User Board</option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="121">User Board</option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-1" value="155">User Board</option> // value is term ID // Content is Boardname
    <option class="level-0" value="226">20</option>         // value is term ID // Content is User ID // User has no boards
</select>

</div>
```

So this is what i have done so far:

```
 $board_parent_id = get_user_meta($user_id, "_Board Parent ID", true);
 $board_children_count = wp_count_terms("board", array( "parent" => $board_parent_id));
```

My idea was to hide the unwanted options with javascript adding "hide". 
So I already have to parent ID and the children count and Im struggling right now, how to go further.

I hope someone here can help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me if the user is using wp-admin or not. But, i'm assuming that your problem is happening in wp-admin.

To hide using javascript, you can do something like this:

```
// Add to footer on admin a function to exec the scripts
add_action('admin_footer', 'my_custom_scripts');

// The function
function my_custom_scripts() {
    // An array of IDs that must be removed
    $itemsIdsToHide = array("121", "226", "123");

    // Create a string to convert the PHP array to JS array
    $strJavascriptArray = "Array('" . implode("','", $itemsIdsToHide) . "')";
    ?>
    <script>
        // Echoes the javascript array created in PHP
        var arr = <?php echo $strJavascriptArray; ?>;

        // Loop into each item of select.
        // BE SURE TO QUERY ONLY THE SELECT YOU NEED
        jQuery('select>option').each(function() {

            // IF the option ID is in the array to remove, remove the item
            if(arr.indexOf($(this).attr("value")) > -1) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <?
}
```

Hope it helps :)